# Quando devo incluir o "../" no caminho para um include ou imagem?

Tags: php, path

Tenho essa dúvida pois hora é necessário apenas o caminho `pasta/arquivo.ext` e hora tenho que colocar `../pasta/arquivo.ext`.

Existe alguma regra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Claro que sim, há regra, imagina que estás a declarar o caminho para a imagem `one.jpg` no ficheiro `index.php` dentro da seguinte estrutura:

```
-index.php
-imgs
    - one.jpg
    - two.jpg
    ...
```

Para este este caso acima usarias assim:

```
imgs/one.jpg
```

Outro caso será:

```
-views
    - index.php
-imgs
    - one.jpg
    - two.jpg
```

Agora terias de declarar que queres retroceder 1 nivel (`../`) na hierarquia das pastas, sendo que o ponto de partida é o próprio `index.php`, ficando assim:

```
../imgs/one.jpg
```

Ou seja, com esta "declaração" (`../`) ficas ao nivel de `views` e de `imgs`, depois sim, podes entrar em `imgs` e completar o caminho com a imagem que queres, e o mesmo vale para caminho mais longos:

```
-public
    -views
        - index.php
-assets
    -imgs
        - one.jpg
        - two.jpg
```

Aqui terias de recuar dois niveis na estrutura para que consigas "entrar" na pasta `assets` e ter acesso às `imgs` e depois à imagem, `../../assets/imgs/one.jpg`

Todas estas utilizações implicam o uso do [caminho relativo](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/), e não o [caminho absoluto](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)